# Download Java JDK through command line

Tags: linux

I have been using the following line to download Java JDK through command line

`wget --no-check-certificate --no-cookies --header "Cookie: oraclelicense=accept-securebackup-cookie" http://download.oracle.com/otn/java/jdk/8u112-b15/jdk-8u112-linux-x64.tar.gz`

Today, it refuses to connect to the URL despite it working before and is still on the site. What might be the problem?

EDIT: https://pastebin.com/vBDq4M02

Comment: Would you please be more specific about "it refuses to connect to the URL..."? I just ran the command and it connected just fine with an authorization error: *Username/Password Authentication Failed.*

Comment: I ran the command again and I have paced the output in the pastebin

Comment: Looks like the website has changed (I'm guessing since this worked in the past). Now going to that page (try it in your browser) forwards you to their login page, which leads wget to a 401 error. http://download.oracle.com/otn/java/jdk/8u112-b15/jdk-8u112-linux-x64.tar.gz